# multiple where clauses in redbeanphp

Tags: php, redbean

I'm using readbeanphp as ORM for my php project. I'm trying to load a bean with an additional where clasue. But i'm not sure how to do this.

Normally i'd get a 'bean' like this:

```
$book = R::load('book', $id);
```

Which is basically like saying:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = '$id'
```

But i need to add another condition in the where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE id = '$id' AND active = 1
```

How can i do this with redbeanphp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedBean_Facade::load` is using for primary key only.

if you want get beans by a complex query
use

`R::find` like,

```
$needles = R::find('needle',' haystack = :haystack 
                                  ORDER BY :sortorder', 
    array( ':sortorder'=>$sortorder, ':haystack'=>$haystack ));
```

Read more about R::find

http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual/finding_beans

try to use getAll to write your query directly with parameters

```
R::getAll( 'select * from book where 
id= :id AND active = :act', 
array(':id'=>$id,':act' => 1) );
```

Read more about queries,

http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual/queries

Comment: Hmm, so there's no other way to get a 'bean' then? I mean, most queries will have atleast multiple WHERE statements and/or an ORDER BY. But if i can only get a bean by using the primary key only. If i really need to use normal sql queries for this, then i might as well drop it right now as this tool seems useless to me.

Comment: If you want get bean. use R::find.I will edit the answer now.

Comment: If the only intended use was to wrap sql queries then you would have a point, but it is much more than that. 'Most queries' ... does that apply to most applications? It's a misleading comment and unqualified statements should be kept to a minimal to avoid misrepresentation and misdirection, intentional or not.

Answer (score 4):

`R::find()` and `R::findOne()` is what you are looking for:

```
$beans=R::find("books","active=? AND id=?",array(1,1));
```

Or if you want a single bean only:

```
$bean=R::findOne("books","active=? AND id=?",array(1,1));
```

`R::find()` will return multiple beans, while `R::findOne()` returns just a single bean.

You technically could use `R::load()` but would have to use PHP to check the `active` field after the bean is loaded to test if it is valid:

```
$bean=R::load("book",$id);
if($bean->active==1){//valid
   //do stuff
}else{//not valid
   //return error
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

these answers are fine but can be simplified. What you should use is:

```
$book = R::find('books', id =:id AND active =:active, array('id' => $id, 'active' => 1));
```

And then you can do your standard foreach to loop through the returned array of data.

Comment: shouldn't you include ":" in the variable names?